# Is it possible to limit permissions when using PnP PowerShell or SharePoint Online Management Shell to a user's existing permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have Microsoft Teams team `Owner` permissions in Office 365 and all users in our organisation can create teams.

Many of my tasks involve introducing efficiencies using tools such as Power Automate,  Term Store Management Tool, Site Columns, Managed Metadata Columns and custom SharePoint Lists and Document Libraries.

As I am an Owner, I can do quite a lot of things, however I do come up against constraints when I want to do further automation (or access data) that involves Graph or SharePoint API.

I have recently put in an IT request to have [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) and [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps) installed.

If these tools are installed, do they enable me to do things that are only possible with my current set of permissions?

Or do they require elevating my permissions to another level?

Additionally, is it possible to 'lock down' the permissions to the Microsoft Teams instances that I am an Owner of, or does the ability to use these tools automatically grant you permissions over *all* resources at the *tenant* level?

To be honest, at this stage I would prefer my capabilities to be limited to what my current permissions allow, because although I have full-stack developer experience and am comfortable working with REST api's, I am relatively new to managing things via PowerShell.

For context, I've also put in a request to register an Azure App so that I can access Microsoft Graph that way, but the request requires granular definition of the permissions I need and I am having difficulty anticipating all the possible permissions I will need (and i'm not sure if I can say 'everything!').

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, the PnP PowerShell or SharePoint Online Management Shell permissions are relate to user's existing permissions. We can't limite it in PnP PowerShell or SharePoint Online Management Shell driectly. When you use PnP PowerShell you have to connect to SharePoint Online with your SP account.